# React native: image-crop-picker crash app Android

Tags: android, react-native

I used react-native-fs to download an image from the server then I used openCropper() from react-native-image-crop-picker to crop. It worked well in iOS, however, it crashed in Android running without any error message or alert.

Have you ever in this issue ? Give me a guide. Thanks everyone.

```
 const onCropImage = async () => {
    setViewImageModal(false);

    const uri = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
    let options = {
      fromUrl: viewImage && viewImage[0].url,
      toFile: uri,
    };

    await RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise;

// App crashed when I call .openCropper() in Android running
    ImageCropPicker.openCropper({
      path: uri,
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
      freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
    })
      .then((image) => {
        if (image) {
          const temp = image.path.split("/");
          const imageName = temp[temp.length - 1];
          navigation.navigate("EditHostScreen", {
            host,
            type: "hosts",
            info: { uri: image.path, typeImage: image.mime, name: imageName },
          });

          const time = setTimeout(() => {
            ImageCropPicker.clean();
            if (uri) {
              RNFS.unlink(uri);
            }
          }, 100000);
          clearTimeout(time);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Have you completed the [installation step for android](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android)? Also, try to clean and rebuild debug apk

Comment: Yah, i missed the specified path.  
... path: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file://${uri}` : uri
 instead of path: uri.
Thank for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the android specific path value.

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

    ImageCropPicker.openCropper({
      path: Platform.OS === "android" ('file://' + uri) : uri,
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
      freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
    })
```

Comment: Oh, that's so nice. Thank you very much

Comment: @hongdeveloper what is the difference between the 2 methods `openCropper` & `openPicker` provided by `react-native-image-crop-picker`, can we use any of them to pick, crop, set an image? because I'm using `openPicker` & when I set `cropping:true` on Android, it crashes without any error, & when `cropping:false` it works fine.